# Is it possible to upgrade sitecore commerce from 9.0.2 to 9.1

Tags: sitecore-commerce, upgrade

I was trying to upgrade `Sitecore commerce from 9.0.2` to 9.1 but couldn't find any documentation for the direct upgrade. It is suggesting to upgrade from `Sitecore commerce 9.0.2` to 9.0.3 and then from 9.0.3 to 9.1.

Is a direct upgrade not possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is **no direct upgrade path from 9.0.2 to 9.1** (for now)

I suggest to install Sitecore Commerce 9.1 from scratch.

Only what you need to do:

- update Visual Studio Nuget Packages references to Sitecore 9.1
  versions
- fix and make compatibility for you custom code (if it's
  needed)
- deploy your customizations

I used this way, instead of migration from version to version and it really saved my time.

More explanation you can find here: 
[Sitecore Commerce Upgrade path](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/16163/sitecore-commerce-upgrade-path)

Comment: This should be a much quicker option, however just be aware this is not a supported/tested upgrade/migration path, and I'm not certain you can export/import your commerce entities easily (as I have not tried this).
Also keep in mind there are quite some big changes both in Commerce as well as in Sitecore (although you'll have to address those whether you go this way or the 'official' upgrade route)

Comment: Sitecore provides postman requests for import/export product catalog/environments. So it shouldn't be an issue. Usually clients already hosted product catalog somewhere and asked to implement product catalog. In this case, you just need to reimport catalog.

Comment: * asked to implement product catalog importer

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct upgrade option. As you can find in the [Sitecore Experience Upgrade Guide](http://commercesdn.sitecore.net/SitecoreXC_9.1/Sitecore_Experience_Commerce_Upgrade_Guide_for_9.1.pdf) to upgrade to Sitecore Experience Commerce 9.1 the prerequisites are:

- Sitecore Experience Platform (XP) 9.0 Update-2
- Sitecore Experience Accelerator (SXA) 1.8.
- Sitecore Experience Commerce (XC) 9.0 Update-3

So your upgrade path is XC9.0.2 -> XC9.0.3 -> XC9.1