# Sitecore XC Upgrade - Sitecore XC 9.0.1 to Sitecore XC 9.0.3

Tags: sitecore-commerce

We would like to upgrade our `Sitecore Commerce` from `XC 9.0.1` to `XC 9.0.3`.

We have refered the following `Sitecore Commerce Upgrade` documents:

http://commercesdn.sitecore.net/SitecoreXC_9.0/Upgrade/Sitecore-XC-9.0_Upgrade_Instructions(U1-to-U2).pdf

http://commercesdn.sitecore.net/SitecoreXC_9.0/Upgrade/Sitecore_Experience_Commerce_Upgrade_Guide_for_9.0.3.pdf

As per the above documents, we have to upgrade to `Sitecore XC 9.0.1` to `Sitecore XC 9.0.2` and after that `Sitecore XC 9.0.3`. So it would be two steps.

Please can somebody tell us:

- Is it possible to update directly to the `Sitecore XC 9.0.3` from `Sitecore XC 9.0.1`?
- If yes, how?
- Is there any document available? Kindly share the URL.

Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No direct upgrade path at this moment.**

You need to upgrade XC 901 to XC 902 and then XC 902 to 903.

The same questions on SSE:

[Sitecore Commerce Upgrade path](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/16163/sitecore-commerce-upgrade-path)

[Is it possible to upgrade sitecore commerce from 9.0.2 to 9.1](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/19078/is-it-possible-to-upgrade-sitecore-commerce-from-9-0-2-to-9-1)